# Purpose of stating "array" without parentheses?

Tags: php, arrays

I got a code snippet from here before and was curious about this syntax that I originally copy-pasted:

```
function create(array &$data){
  #blah blah...
}
```

What is the purpose of `array &$data` as opposed to `&$data` by itself?
In other words, what does the statement `array` do in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> PHP 5 introduces type hinting. Functions are now able to force
>   parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the
>   function prototype), interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable
>   (since PHP 5.4). However, if NULL is used as the default parameter
>   value, it will be allowed as an argument for any later call.
>
> If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children
>   or implementations are allowed too.
>
> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.
>   Traits are not allowed either.